# Is there a `before_read` callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There isn't but I want to know how you would do the following. I'm trying to "intercept" an attribute and overwrite it with an another attribute if certain conditions are set:

```
# pseudo code
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_read :intercept_attributes

    def intercept_attributes
       if self.is_soft_deleted?
         define_method content do
            "This message was deleted #{time_ago_in_words(self.soft_deleted_at)} ago"
         end
       end
    end

end
```

A post has the following attributes: `content`, and `soft_deleted_at`

For this post:

```
normal_post = Post.first
=> #<Post id: 0, content: "I am a fine comment", soft_deleted_at: nil >
```

The comment is displayed no problem:

```
normal_post.comment #=> "I am a find comment"
```

But for this post:

```
soft_deleted_post = Post.last
=> #<Post id: 1, content: "I am a naughty post", soft_deleted_at: Tue, 15 Apr 2014 16:24:09 +0100 >
```

I want this to happen:

```
soft_deleted_post.comment #=> "This message was deleted about five minutes ago"
```

So how should I go about doing this? If there was a before_read callback this would work, but I don't want to go against the grain of rails. So how could I do this?

**Note that a class method would be no good here, because I need access to the `self` keyword. `(self.soft_deleted_at)`**

Comment: That sounds bad to modify the object before displaying it -- imagine your app sends a save to the object? It would save the content with the message "This message was deleted ..."

Answer (score 3):

You can simply overwrite `content` method like this

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base    
    def content
       if is_soft_deleted?
            "This message was deleted #{time_ago_in_words(self.soft_deleted_at)} ago"
       else 
            self[:content]
       end
    end   
end
```

If you want to access the original content you may rename this method to something like `display_content` or whatever name matches your domain language best.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think doing this in your models is a very good practice. You should either do it in your helpers or, if you don't like that approach like many people, have a look at decorators:

https://github.com/drapergem/draper

http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper